# Uniform angular distribution of unit vectors in a unit sphere

Tags: vectors

What is the maximum uniform angular spacing between $N$ number of unit vectors when they all start from the same origin?

In other terms,  I need to position $N$ unit vectors into a unit sphere such that no 2 vectors form an angle that is less than the other pair of vectors.

Comment: Your question is closely related to placing points uniformly spaced around a sphere and you probably won't like the answer. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212550/distributing-points-evenly-on-a-sphere

Comment: Thanks! Luckily I only needed for 14, seems like it is solved https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.2536.pdf